# ffmpeg stereo3d not working with scale

Tags: ffmpeg, stereo

I used this command to recode stereo video:

```
ffmpeg -i seav.mp4 -vf stereo3d=abl:sbsl -c:a copy seah.mp4
```

But when I add scale it fails:

```
ffmpeg -i seav.mp4 -vf stereo3d=abl:sbsl scale=2560x720 -c:a copy seah.mp4
```

Comment: Unable to find a suitable output format for 'scale=2560x720' what is the suitable?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Do you get an error?  Please edit that into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters have to be separated by commas.

```
ffmpeg -i seav.mp4 -vf stereo3d=abl:sbsl,scale=2560x720 -c:a copy seah.mp4
```

You also can't have whitespace between filters, unless they're enclosed in quotes: `-vf "stereo3d=abl:sbsl, scale=2560x720"`